# How to send instant message to Windows Phone 7 from C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

A very straight forward question, but I know there would be no easy answer. I am looking for ideas on how to communicate to Windows Phone 7 back and forth using our application written in c#.

Our purpose is to receive user responses back to application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer goes something like this...

1) When you need a response, send a push notification to the phone app.  This requires the user to opt in to receipt of push notifications for that app.
2) On startup of the phone app, have it query a service to retrieve outstanding information requests.  This service will be the phone app's sole means of communicating with the underlying app, so make sure you can do all you need through the service (get and submit data, mainly)
3) Display the required form to gather user input, and submit the values supplied.

Of course, you can make the scenario as complex or as simple as you like - add a count to the push notification (tile) to show the user they have outstanding data entry requirements - in case they miss the toast notification, have a background job that polls for work to complete, that kind of thing, but in my own opinion,  a simple push tile notification should give you what you need.

Comment: I just read in a book that its not a reliable method. Yes we can communicate with mobile apps, but we cant rely on that method only. what you would recomannd?

Comment: They are not 00% reliable, it's true.  However, that's pretty much your only real option.  When you add in the check at startup to poll for new data, that should cover your scenarios well enough.  While it is possible to use sockets in the new version of WP7, the overhead in terms of writing background agents to do the polling is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sockets with the latest WP7.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202874(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Derek, our application is WinForm based.Can you share your experience?

Comment: My exp with sockets on WP7 is the extent of this example:http://goo.gl/2FNWP which is a WP7 app talking to a console app.  Sockets should work fine but I don't know exactly what you want to accomplish and how you deal with the phone sleeping etc.

Comment: Derek, this is my first application for WP7. We r developing Vehicle Tracking and Job Dispatch System. Where we will be communicating with the delivery man using the app. We will send the delivery man a msg using our winform app and it will appear on the delivery man's screen(WP7) and he will update us with the response by clicking on the available option. like he accepted or rejected the new delivery and we want his response back in our application and then save it into database. I hope this will give you some idea.

Comment: In that case ZombieSheeps answer is probably more of what you're looking for.  Use push notifications to tell the driver about something.  Then they can fire up the app to do something with that info.

Comment: But Push Notifications, are not reliable. thats what I have read in the book. What do you think about communication via email? like we will send the email with some xml and our application at mobile will intercept the mail from exchange server and based on the xml inside it will act.? but I dont know how solid this would be thats why I am looking for some suggestions here?

Comment: Do you own/control the devices and do the delivery men work for the same employer?